# ANTLR v4 Check if String is valid for the given grammar

Tags: t-sql, parsing, antlr

Using the TSQL grammar from here https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql

I have generated .java classes and imported to my project, now I would like to check if given string is valid for the grammar or not.

So for example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

Should return true

And:

```
SELECT + blah;
```

Should return false

Is it even possible with ANTLR or I am just misunderstanding the concept of it?

Comment: I don't know anything about ANTLR and don't fully understand what you're trying to do. If ANTLR does not work for you perhaps you can pass T-SQL code to a TRY/CATCH block using the CATCH to sniff for bad T-SQL syntax.

Comment: "Using official TSQL grammar [...]", hold on: grammars from that Github repo are pretty much all user contributions (and many of them lack any form of testing). Also note the comment: "This is a community supported grammar file for t-sql, it is cool, yet not very complete so far because a grammar reference of T-SQL is hard to find."

Comment: Well, I am not saying it is not working. I am saying that I have no idea what method should I use to check it. There are many pregenerated methods but I am a little bit confused.

Comment: My point is that by saying "Using official TSQL grammar", you might think it is a complete (valid) grammar, which it is (most probably) not. I don't recommend using it if you're not entirely sure how to fix issues that might arise from it. I recommend finding an existing (proven) parser instead.

Comment: There is not anything like proven parser.

Comment: There is a big difference between a user-contributed grammar there and parser with a fair amount of unit tests. But, to answer your question "Is it even possible with ANTLR?": yes, that is possible :). If your next question is "how can I do it?", then I'd recommend you to go read up on ANTLR, try to solve it yourself first, and post back here when you run into problems. Best of luck!

Comment: Man, I know how to gen the Parser and Lexer files. The thing is, there is no method to check if the grammar string matches or not. I guess there should be something like this. Tsql grammar has a few contributors and its updated so I guess it works, but how ? There is 0 documentation regarding to that so how can I even start to code something when I have no docs whatsoever.